# Maintaining formating while replacing words in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I've written a short program that goes through a text file and replaces abbreviations within a file with the spelled out word. The following is my code:

```
acronyms = {'USA': 'United States of America', 'UK': 'United Kingdom'}

paper = "Emails.txt"

with open(paper) as main:
    words = main.read().split('\s')

text = ' '.join(acronyms.get(y, y) for y in words)

paper = paper.rstrip(".txt")
new_name = ''.join([paper,"_clarified.txt"]) 

with open(new_name, 'w') as f:
    for word in text:
         f.write(word)
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to accomplish my task and maintain the text file's formatting. I'm not even sure what the problem is now - if I use `words = main.read().split('\s')` none of the abbreviations are replaced, while if I use  `words = main.read().split()` it works perfectly. I'd appreciate any guidance on the matter, even if it's just being pointed in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `split()` works perfectly... what is the problem? What do you mean by 'maintain formatting'?

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford I mean the empty lines and spaces that make a document readable. Spaces between different emails, for example. Right now my Emails_clarified file is just a giant block of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `/s` won't actually return anything, and splitting on *all* whitespace discards the type of whitespace you split on. So turn what you're doing on it's head:

```
>>> original_text = "Go USA\n Hail UK\n"
>>> acronyms = {"USA": "America", "UK": "Britannia"}
    for acronym in acronyms:
...     original_text = acronyms[acronym].join(original_text.split(acronym))
... 
>>> original_text
... 'Go America\n Hail Britannia\n'
```

So, rather than tokenize and convert everything at once, you make a pass over the document for every acronym you want to replace and modify the document. When you're done with every modification you output the final result.

Comment: Yay! I'm glad it did.